# Performance Issue: Spring batch job taking too long to insert rows in DB

Tags: oracle, performance, spring-batch

Created spring batch job to read from file and write to DB, the program accepts dynamic columns, i.e. can be used for any table. The util is working fine but it's taking more than 1 hour to load 1 million records. Please help to fix this!

```
 <bean id="FileItemReader" class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemReader"
                scope="step">
                <!-- Read a csv file -->
                <property name="resource"
                    value="file:#{stepExecutionContext['file']}" />
                <property name="lineMapper">
                    <bean class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.mapping.DefaultLineMapper">
                        <!-- split it -->
                        <property name="lineTokenizer">
                            <bean class="com.mypack.LineTokenizer">
                                <property name="delimiter" value="|" /> 
                                <property name="tableName" value="#{stepExecutionContext['tablename']}" />
                                <property name="dataSource" ref="dtsoruce" />
                            </bean>
                        </property>
                        <property name="fieldSetMapper" ref="mapper" />
                    </bean>
                </property>

                <property name="linesToSkip" value="0" />
            </bean>

            <bean id="mapper" class="com.mypack.MapFieldSetMapper" scope="step"/>

        <bean id="DbItemWriter" class="com.mypack.Filewrtr" scope="step">
                <property name="dataSource" ref="dtsoruce" />
                <property name="tableName" value="#{stepExecutionContext['tablename']}" />
            </bean>
        </beans>

        public class LineTokenizer extends DelimitedLineTokenizer implements InitializingBean {

            private String columnNames = "SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM ALL_TAB_COLS  WHERE  TABLE_NAME =";
            private String tableName;
            private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

            protected JdbcTemplate createJdbcTemplate(DataSource dataSource) {
                return new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
            }
            public final void setDataSource(DataSource dataSource) {
                if (this.jdbcTemplate == null || dataSource != this.jdbcTemplate.getDataSource()) {
                    this.jdbcTemplate = createJdbcTemplate(dataSource);
                    initTemplateConfig();
                }
            }
            protected void initTemplateConfig() {
            }
            public final JdbcTemplate getJdbcTemplate() {
                  return this.jdbcTemplate;
                }

            public void afterPropertiesSet() throws Exception {
                jdbcTemplate.execute("TRUNCATE TABLE "+tableName);
                logger.debug("TABLE TRUNCATED SUCCESSFULLY :"+tableName);
                String[] names;
                int i=0;
                List<Map<String,Object>> columns=jdbcTemplate.queryForList(columnNames+"'"+tableName+"' ORDER BY COLUMN_ID");
                names=new String[columns.size()];
                for(Map<String,Object> convert:columns){
                    for(String key:convert.keySet()){
                        names[i]=(String) convert.get(key);
                        i++;
                    }
                }
                this.names = names==null ? null : Arrays.asList(names).toArray(new String[names.length]);
                logger.debug("FIELDS NAME => "+names);
                Filewrtr.columnNames=names;

            }
        }
        public class Filewrtr extends JdbcDaoSupport implements ItemWriter<Map<String, String>>{

            private String tableName;
            private String sql;
            private Object[] data;
            public static String columnNames[];

            public void write(final List<? extends Map<String, String>>  items)
                    throws Exception {
                String columntype = "INSERT INTO " + tableName + "(";
                String value = ") VALUES(";
                int i = 0;
                for (String key : columnNames) {
                    if (i != (columnNames.length - 1)) {
                        columntype = columntype + key + ",";
                        value = value + "?,";

        logger.info("column type"+columntype+"value"+value);
                    } else {
                        columntype = columntype + key;
                    }
                    i++;
                }

                sql = columntype + value + "?)";
                this.getJdbcTemplate().batchUpdate(sql, new BatchPreparedStatementSetter() {
                    public void setValues(PreparedStatement ps, int i) throws SQLException {
                        int j = 1;
                        for (String tradeColumn : columnNames) {
                            if(isValid(items.get(i).get(tradeColumn)))
                            {
                                SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
                                try
                                {
                                    Date time = df.parse(items.get(i).get(tradeColumn));

                                    ps.setDate(j, new java.sql.Date(time.getTime()));
                                }catch(Exception e)
                                {
                                    ps.setTimestamp(j, null);
                                }
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                    ps.setString( j , items.get(i).get(tradeColumn));

                            }
                            j++;
                        }
                    }
                    public int getBatchSize() {
                        return items.size();
                    }
                });
            }
        }
```

Comment: Did you profile your code to check where is the bottleneck?

Comment: Is LineTokenizer#afterPropertiesSet() executed once or multiple times? Maybe truncate is taking too much time in which case you can use a step listener

Comment: only once. and its not taking much time.checked it.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I can't help you more :( Identify which parts of your code are slow and review them

Comment: What `batchSize`are you using? *items.size()?*  Test with different sizes say 1000, 5000, 10K... and note - your are on nearly 280 records / second - this is for Hibernate & Co. rather exceptional:)

Comment: Unless you can do some profiling and let us know what the bottleneck is, there isn't much we can do to help.

Answer (score 0):

Oracle provides a utility, SQL Loader Express, to load a CSV file without the need to write complex code.

Comment: Hi bobC, I need to do this using Spring batch,its project requirement

Comment: You are using the wrong tool for the job. Using the correct tool, you should be able to load in seconds. I can probably help you make some suggestions to make this a little faster; but what happens when you get a billion row file? Or 10 of them?  I would encourage you to challenge these project requirements.

Comment: we have already done.. using spring batch.. but that is for a static columns.. but this is for dynamic columns. And the end users are only aware to run spring batch job

Comment: @BobC, In most cases you are not allowed/supposed to execute scripts on DB, this requires to login to DB server which is security vulnerability and oracle provides clients, in this case you need to install them on your machine, which from deployment and maintenance perspective not feasible.  There are few more other constraint. Hence rarely few people use sql loader in prod.

Comment: I work with many clients who provide access to the DB. Server for this purpose. In addition, you can can run sqlloader from a client machine.

Comment: @KarthikPrasad: Any suggestions on this issue?

Comment: Questions/ suggestions: 1. Are there any indexes/constraints on your table? If so, drop and rebuild after the load. 2. Make your batch size large, eg 1024. 3. Does Spring convert your insert statement into an array insert? If not, then you should code that. 4. Use the APPEND_VALUES hint to do a direct path load.

Comment: this util is being is used to regularly and we have many tables so cant define seperate job for each table.

Comment: @BobC: yes we have we have indexex and constraints and i have dnt drop previlage and its not only me who is going to use this util, so i can ask the users to drop and create these.